# a decorator function that slows down the execution of another function javascript

Tags: javascript, decorator

a decorator function that slows down the execution of an arbitrary function by 5 seconds.

```
function someFunction(a, b) {
        console.log(a + b);
    }
function slower(func, seconds) {
// decorator code
}
let slowedSomeFunction = slower(someFunction, 5);
slowedSomeFunction()
// will output to the console "You will get you result in 5 seconds"
//...in 5 seconds will display the result of 'someFunction*'
```

attempts were unsuccessful, there are errors in the code

```
function someFunction(x) {
    alert(x);
}

function slower(func, seconds) {
    return function() {
        setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, arguments), seconds);
    }
}

let slowedSomeFunction = slower(alert, 5); 

slowedSomeFunction('You will get you result in 5 seconds');
```

Comment: look up lodash throttle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
function someFunction(a, b) {
    console.log(a + b);
}

function slower(func, seconds) {
    return function() {
        console.log("You will get your result in " + seconds + " seconds");
        setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, arguments), seconds * 1000);
    }
}

let slowedSomeFunction = slower(someFunction, 5);
slowedSomeFunction(2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure to understand what you're trying to do but your function seems to work. The only issue is that the setTimeout() takes an argument in milliseconds and not seconds so you need to multiply it by 1 000 if you want seconds:

```
function someFunction(x) {
    alert(x);
}

function slower(func, seconds) {
    return function() {
        setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, arguments), seconds*1000);
    }
}

let slowedSomeFunction = slower(someFunction, 5); 

slowedSomeFunction('Chill out, you will get you result in 5 seconds');
```